# Laravel error deprecated issue after artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When ever I run an artisan command I am getting this issue.

> PHP Deprecated:  Return type of
> Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/mat/project/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 1352

I am using PHP 8.1.2. I have tried changing versions of PHP, clear cache, composer install && upgrade but I still get this issue.

Thanks in advance at all.

Comment: According to [this bug report](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/39795), it was fixed in Laravel 8.53, so run `composer update`

Comment: I try composer update and also composer upgrade, this command are basic. But the result is not change!

Comment: If you do `php artisan --version`, what do you get?

Comment: Return the same errror, for reasons of length I put the output here
 : https://pastebin.pl/view/51c4ed69

Comment: Delete your vendor folder and run `composer install`, it should get the newer version of everything